# Error:Could not create Java Virtual Machine while running hadoop commands

Tags: hadoop, jvm

I am not able to run hadoop commands on my Ubuntu OS.I have hadoop version 2.7.3. I have installed java version openjdk 11.0.2.

The command 'hadoop' and 'java -version' is working perfectly fine.I am getting following error.

```
Unrecognized option: -
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: What hadoop command are you running ?

Comment: Hadoop 2.7 was released before Java 11... You likely need Java 8 or upgrade Hadoop

Comment: I am getting error on command 'haddop version' and all other commnds@RahulKadukar

Comment: Ok I will upgrade hadoop@cricket_007